# Issu with XSS attack in siteminder fcc files

Tags: xss, siteminder

i have any Fcc files which contain  some hidden variable which out testing team isattacking like   with a parameter **TARGET=-SM-http%3a%2f%2fgrow%2egoogle%2ecom%2f%22%20%73%54%79%4c%65%3d%58%3a%65%58%70%52%65%53%73%49%6f%4e%28%61%6c%65%72%74%28%34%37%36%38%33%29%29%20%22**
which is making  target variable to act as below

INPUT type='hidden' name='target' value='' STYLE= xss:expression(alert('attack alert'))" '
which  will  result to alert message in finte loop

my form contain  some form values which as hidden 
   name="target" value="$$target$$"
   name="smauthreason" value="$$smauthreason$$"

these form values will assign to form elements

so how can i avoid xss attack issue